# For Amazon EventBridge rule, does default event bus need to be permissions to dispatch events to Kinesis Firehose?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-connect

Related query is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77018018/in-amazon-eventbridge-which-schema-for-contact-events-is-actually-dispatched-by).

When I create a rule for Amazon EventBridge to subscribe to Contact Events from Amazon Connect, and then dispatch them to a Kinesis Firehose, the process of creating that rule in turn creates a new permissions policy, named something like `Amazon_EventBridge_Invoke_Firehose_12345678`.  That policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "firehose:PutRecord",
                "firehose:PutRecordBatch"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:firehose:us-west-2:1234567890:deliverystream/my-firehose"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I presume this permissions policy is attached to the rule.  But nowhere in the EventBridge dashboard can I see where this policy is used.

QUESTION:  does said policy need to be attached to the EventBridge in some way?  And does the default event bus need to be explicitly permissioned to dispatch events to Kinesis Firehose?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the AWS console, EventBridge will automatically configure the proper permissions for the selected targets. The IAM role created will be displayed in the Target section of the EventBridge rule.

[image]